# composer.json para un Child Theme de WordPress

Tags: composer

Intentaré explicar mi problema lo mejor posible. Quiero que al instalar un tema de WordPress que depende de otro (osea el que quiero instalar es un Child Theme), se descargue automáticamente el tema padre.

En el archivo `composer.json` tengo lo siguiente:

```
{
    "name": "rogertm/themingisprose",
    "description": "Twenty'em Child Theme",
    "keywords": ["wordpress", "framework", "child theme"],
    "homepage": "https://themingisprose.com",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "type": "wordpress-theme",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0",
        "composer/installers": "^1.0",
        "rogertm/twenty-em": "1.2.*"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "RogerTM",
            "email": "roger213tm@gmail.com",
            "homepage": "https://themingisprose.com",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ]
}
```

Si le quitara la línea `"rogertm/twenty-em": "1.2.*"` funciona perfectamente, el tema se instala en el directorio `wp-content/themes/` sin problemas, pero en este caso me da un error:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> - Installation request for rogertm/themingisprose dev-master -> satisfiable by rogertm/themingisprose[dev-master].
> - rogertm/themingisprose dev-master requires rogertm/twenty-em 1.2.* -> no matching package found.
>
> Potential causes:
>
> - A typo in the package name
> - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting see
>     https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more
>     details.

Si instalo el tema padre (framework) directamente no presenta ningún problema, pueden ver el archivo [composer.json](https://github.com/rogertm/twenty-em/blob/master/composer.json)...

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Gracias de antemano...